# Django form isn't showing the correct fields

Tags: python, html, django, forms, field

The django form to let users change their  information fields should let them change username, email, name and last_name, but instead, it shows their nationality, gender, score on app and birthday.

**views.py**

```
def  profileedit_view(request):
    if request.method== 'POST':
        form= PerfilEditadoForm(request.POST, instance = request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            form= PerfilEditadoForm(instance=request.user)
            args= {'form': form}
            return render(request, 'profileedit', args)

    form = UsuarioForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, "profileedit.html", context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class PerfilEditadoForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields= ('email', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

**profileedit.py**

```
<form method="POST" action="#"> {% csrf_token %}
        <p>
        {{ form.as_ul }}
        <button class="btn btn-primary py-1 px-2" type="submit" > Save </button>
        </p>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is being overridden by `form = UsuarioForm(request.POST or None)`. Assuming the fields you want to show belong to PerfilEditadoForm, you should change that line to `form = PerfilEditadoForm(request.POST or None)`.

My suggestion would be to move that particular line just before the `if request.method== 'POST':`. Something like

```
def  profileedit_view(request):
    form= PerfilEditadoForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method== 'POST':
        form.instance = request.user
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            form= PerfilEditadoForm(instance=request.user)
            args= {'form': form}
            return render(request, 'profileedit', args)

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, "profileedit.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

In forms.py
change the brackets- use [] instead of ()

```
class PerfilEditadoForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields= ['email', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name']
```